# Photoshop: Change Text Box Position Coordinates Via Script

Tags: text, photoshop-scripting

Here's what I'd like to do.

```
textLayer.textItem.position[0] = 200;
```

I would expect this to change the x-coordinate of the text box to 200px from the canvas origin. The value does not get assigned. Anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I can recreate your scenario and I am not sure why it behaves this way. However, the following workaround is possible:

```
var y = textLayer.textItem.position[1];
textLayer.textItem.position = [200, y];
```

For some reason, the individual values of the `UnitValue` array are not mutable and we have to set `position` as a new array.